# Add User to Azure Active Directory using https://graph.microsoft.com with ActiveDirectoryClient

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I'm trying to add a user to my Azure tenant's Active Directory.

I'm using `Microsoft Graph API`. The same one exposed through Graph Explorer [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

The problem is that no matter what `serviceRoot` **URI** I pass, I'm getting an exception.

I successfully get a token in `GetTokenForApplication` method:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                      async () => await GetTokenForApplication());
```

However, when I call:

```
await activeDirectoryClient.Users.AddUserAsync(aadUser);
```

It throws this exception:

```
 "{\r\n
    \"error\": {\r\n
                   \"code\": \"BadRequest\",\r\n
                   \"message\": \"Query parameter api-version not allowed\",\r\n    
                   \"innerError\": {\r\n
                                    \"request-id\": \"57327a85-8320-4363-b5f9-aeacdf782861\",\r\n
                                    \"date\": \"2019-05-30T21:59:55\"\r\n
                                   }\r\n
               }\r\n
}"
```

This is the `serviceRoot` **URI** I'm using: "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0"

What URI should I pass in **serviceRoot**?

Is `ActiveDirectoryClient` compatible with `Microsoft Graph`? I ask because the sample where I saw `ActiveDirectoryClient` being used was using `Azure AD Graph API`.

This [blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2016/07/08/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/) shows the difference between the old `Azure AD Graph API` and the new `Microsoft Graph API`. By the way: Microsoft advises us to use `Microsoft Graph API` because all new development is going to be concentrated on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to use the newer Microsoft Graph API (`https://graph.microsoft.com`) but using the client library for older Azure AD Graph API (`https://graph.windows.net`)

You can read about the comparison in detail here - [Microsoft Graph or the Azure AD Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/office/blogs/microsoft-graph-or-azure-ad-graph/)

Here are nuget package and class details:

**Microsoft Graph API**

- `Microsoft.Graph` nuget package - to work with `Microsoft Graph API` and use `GraphServiceClient` class.

**Azure AD Graph API**

- `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient` nuget package - to work with Azure AD Graph API and use `ActiveDirectoryClient` class.

**Code for Microsoft Graph API Client**

Microsoft Docs - [Create User - SDK Sample Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#sdk-sample-code)

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var user = new User
{
    AccountEnabled = true,
    DisplayName = "displayName-value",
    MailNickname = "mailNickname-value",
    UserPrincipalName = "upn-value@tenant-value.onmicrosoft.com",
    PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile
    {
        ForceChangePasswordNextSignIn = true,
        Password = "password-value"
    }
};

await graphClient.Users
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(user);
```

Comment: Exactly this... I just found a sample project after posting this question. The project contains snippets for Microsoft Graph: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample ... took a look at the code and saw they are using `GraphServiceClient` from `Microsoft.Graph` NuGet package. You nailed it! Thanks.

Comment: For B2C you should still use Azure AD Graph (https://graph.windows.net). It exposes some user attributes which MS Graph does not.

Comment: I tried to add a user with a GMail account and it failed with `{"Code: Request_BadRequest\r\nMessage: Property userPrincipalName is invalid.\r\n\r\nInner error\r\n"}`... question: to add external accounts \ non Organization accounts will I need to use Azure AD Graph or I do need a B2C directory?

Comment: I think there is a different api available for inviting external users.. take a look here.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs#sdk-sample-code .. the one you're using right now is to create an Azure AD user, so it would need to belong to verified domain I guess.

Comment: Graph is for adding local users to b2C, not federated like Gmail. You can't add a Gmail user since you know their Gmail internal user id. Rather let these users signup and perhaps use a REST function to add any additional attributes you have about them somewhere else. Azure AD Graph is just a REST API (alternative to MS Graph). It should be used for B2C user operations.

Comment: I am terribly sorry: I though I had searched for B2C related queries. Yours is not B2C related so my comments are irrelevant. Please ignore. Use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api to invite Gmail users to the regular AAD tenant. Make sure that you federate your tenant with Gmail first.